# Ruby on Rails seems to be auto-escaping html created by link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Here is my code, I'm trying to display a list of links to a bboy's crews in sentence form with .to_sentence

```
<span class="affiliation">
    <% if(@bboy.crews.count > 0)%>
    <span><%= if(@bboy.crews.size > 1) then "Crew".pluralize else "Crew" end %>:</span>
    <%= @bboy.crews.collect{|c| link_to c.name, c}.to_sentence %>
    <% else %>  
    <em>Independent</em>
    <% end %>
</span>
```

The output I get is the correct links but it displays as:

```
<a href="/crews/1">Hustle Kidz</a> and <a href="/crews/2">Knuckleheads Cali</a>
```

rather than:

> [Hustle Kidz](/crews/1) and
>   [Knuckleheads
>   Cali](/crews/2)

with the html escaped, rather than the desired links.

Am I missing something? I've tried CGI.unescapeHTML and a few others but am getting lost...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Kleber S, you should move this into a helper, because that's a lot of logic for a view

```
def crews_description(crews)
  if crews.empty?
    content_tag('em', 'Independent')
  else
    label = "Crew"
    label = label.pluralize if crews.size > 1
    crews_links = crews.map {|crew| link_to(h(crew.name), crew)}.to_sentence
    content_tag('span', label) + crews_links.html_safe
  end
end
```

and in your view:

```
<span class="affiliation">
  <%= crews_description(@bboy.crews)
</span>
```

Answer (score 20):

Rails 3 now automatically escapes everything, in order to output raw HTML use this:

```
<%= some_string.html_safe %>
```

or this:

```
<%= raw @some_html_string %>
```

Thanks to [macek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/184600/macek) for a hint.

For additional details: http://markconnell.co.uk/posts/2010/02/rails-3-html-escaping

Comment: Awesome, that worked great! I also just noticed it was working when bboy.crews.size was 1 but not when it was greater than 1... Any idea why?

Comment: I think that's because when there is just one element in an array of crew members - "to_sentence" method doesn't create a ruby string from all the links and that's why Rails doesn't escape it, and usual link_to works.

Answer (score 4):

You can (and should) you the `raw` method

```
<%= raw @some_html_string %>
```

Comment: +1 for using raw (which can be inlined by the template pre-processor, so it's faster) instead of html_safe (http://yehudakatz.com/2010/02/01/safebuffers-and-rails-3-0/ summary, bullet 3)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you move this block of code to an helper and then use the .html_safe method to obtain the expected results.

Comment: Why should it be moved to a helper?