# html entities in haml

Tags: haml, html-entities

How do you write:

```
= link_to 'Select »', "/"
```

in HAML properly?

```
= link_to 'Select &raquo;', "/"
```

just prints `&raquo;` again.

**ANSWER FROM Phrogz**

```
= link_to('Select &raquo;'.html_safe,'/')
```

did the trick

Comment: I know nothing about HAML, but: What happens if you say `= link_to 'Select &amp;raquo;', "/"` ?

Comment: prints the whole literal thing :P

Comment: Have you been bitten by markup in Stack Overflow? Should the last line of your question actually say _"just prints &raquo; again"_ or _"just prints » again"_? I'm confused by what you want to output, what your code is, and what you are seeing instead.

Comment: woops yeah i have been DEVOURED by that markup lol. thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the simplest test, Haml does not futz with your HTML entities:

```rb
> require "haml"
#=> true
> Haml::Engine.new('%p= "See &raquo;"').render
#=> "<p>See &raquo;</p>\n"
```

Your problem is probably not `Haml`, but rather explicit HTML escaping with `link_to` or Rails itself.

For example, see [this question](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/52179) and also:
[Ruby on Rails seems to be auto-escaping html created by link_to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5434767/ruby-on-rails-seems-to-be-auto-escaping-html-created-by-link-to)

If you are using Haml with Rails, perhaps try:

```rb
= raw link_to('Select &raquo;','/')
```

Alternatively, I would just use proper Unicode throughout your pipeline so that there is no chance that an `&` will be turned into `&amp;` accidentally.

Comment: raw link_to('Select &raquo;','/') still gives me raquo instead of >> when rendered though

Comment: hmm but looking at the code via inspector shows that it is still >> shouldn't it be raquo in the code but >> when viewed?