# Why is this JS code giving me a syntax error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I get this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

This is my super messy code in my update.js.erb file that's giving me the error:

```
$(".comments_div").html("<% @video.comment_titles.each do |comment_title| %> \
<div class ="comment_column_<%= 
 case @video.comment_titles.count 
    when 1 
        "wide" 
    when 2 
    "medium" 
    when 3 
        "narrow" 
    else 
        return 
    end 
%>"> \
    <% unless @video.comment_titles.count == 0 %> \
    <div id = "comment_title_<%= comment_title.id %>" class="comment_title"> \
        <%= comment_title.title %> \
        <%= link_to "x", comment_title_path(comment_title.id), :method => :delete, :remote => true, :class => 'comment_title_delete' %> \
    </div> \
        <% comment_title.comments.each do |comment| %> \
            <div class='comment_content'>  \
              <%= link_to image_tag(comment.user.profile.photo.url(:tiny)), profile_path(comment.user.profile), :class => "comment_image" %> \
              <div class='textual_comment_content'> \
              <div class='comment_text'> \
                 <span class="name_link"> \
                     <%= link_to "#{comment.user.name}", profile_path(comment.user.profile), :class => 'normal' %> \
                 </span> \
                 <%= comment.body %> \
              </div> \
              <span class='comment_footer'> \
                 <ul> \
                    <li class='list_style'><%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %> ago</li> \
                    <% unless current_user != comment.user %> \
                        <li><%= link_to "Delete", video_comment_path(:video_id => @video, :id => comment), :method => :delete, :class => 'normal' %></li> \
                    <% end %> \
                 </ul> \
              </span> \
              </div> \
            </div> \
        <% end %> \
     </div> \
    <% end %> \
<% end %>");
```

This is what the browser sees:

```
$(".comments_div").html(" \
<div class ="comment_column_medium"> \
     \
    <div id = "comment_title_39" class="comment_title"> \
        Do you like this song? \
        <a href="/comment_titles/39" class="comment_title_delete" data-method="delete" data-remote="true" rel="nofollow">x</a> \
    </div> \
         \
            <div class='comment_content'>  \
              <a href="/profiles/45" class="comment_image"><img alt="Justin meltzer" src="/system/photos/45/tiny/Justin Meltzer.jpeg?1302075215" /></a> \
              <div class='textual_comment_content'> \
              <div class='comment_text'> \
                 <span class="name_link"> \
                     <a href="/profiles/45" class="normal">Justin Meltzer</a> \
                 </span> \
                 Ok so this is what I think about this song: You need to switch back to your roots. You started as a rapper, and you need to remain a rapper. I respect you for your initiative to improve your flexibility but please stick to your roots. That's what makes you truly great. \
              </div> \
              <span class='comment_footer'> \
                 <ul> \
                    <li class='list_style'>about 17 hours ago</li> \
                     \
                        <li><a href="/videos/485/comments/22" class="normal" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow">Delete</a></li> \
                     \
                 </ul> \
              </span> \
              </div> \
            </div> \
         \
     </div> \
     \
 \
<div class ="comment_column_medium"> \
     \
    <div id = "comment_title_71" class="comment_title"> \
        ascasc sc \
        <a href="/comment_titles/71" class="comment_title_delete" data-method="delete" data-remote="true" rel="nofollow">x</a> \
    </div> \
         \
     </div> \
     \
");
```

UPDATED .JS.ERB CODE:

```
$(".comments_div").html('<% @video.comment_titles.each do |comment_title| %> \
<div class ="comment_column_<%= 
 case @video.comment_titles.count 
    when 1 
        "wide" 
    when 2 
       "medium" 
    when 3 
        "narrow" 
    else 
        return 
    end 
%>"> \
    <% unless @video.comment_titles.count == 0 %> \
    <div id = "comment_title_<%= comment_title.id %>" class="comment_title"> \
        <%= comment_title.title %> \
        <%= link_to "x", comment_title_path(comment_title.id), :method => :delete, :remote => true, :class => "comment_title_delete" %> \
    </div> \
        <% comment_title.comments.each do |comment| %> \
            <div class="comment_content">  \
              <%= link_to image_tag(comment.user.profile.photo.url(:tiny)), profile_path(comment.user.profile), :class => "comment_image" %> \
              <div class="textual_comment_content"> \
              <div class="comment_text"> \
                 <span class="name_link"> \
                     <%= link_to "#{comment.user.name}", profile_path(comment.user.profile), :class => "normal" %> \
                 </span> \
                 <%= comment.body %> \
              </div> \
              <span class="comment_footer"> \
                 <ul> \
                    <li class="list_style"><%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %> ago</li> \
                    <% unless current_user != comment.user %> \
                        <li><%= link_to "Delete", video_comment_path(:video_id => @video, :id => comment), :method => :delete, :class => "normal" %></li> \
                    <% end %> \
                </ul> \
              </span> \
              </div> \
            </div> \
        <% end %> \
     </div> \
    <% end %> \
<% end %>');
```

UPDATED JS/HTML SEEN BY BROWSER:

```
$(".comments_div").html(' \
<div class ="comment_column_narrow"> \
     \
    <div id = "comment_title_39" class="comment_title"> \
        Do you like this song? \
        <a href="/comment_titles/39" class="comment_title_delete" data-method="delete" data-remote="true" rel="nofollow">x</a> \
    </div> \
         \
            <div class="comment_content">  \
              <a href="/profiles/45" class="comment_image"><img alt="Justin meltzer" src="/system/photos/45/tiny/Justin Meltzer.jpeg?1302075215" /></a> \
              <div class="textual_comment_content"> \
              <div class="comment_text"> \
                 <span class="name_link"> \
                     <a href="/profiles/45" class="normal">Justin Meltzer</a> \
                 </span> \
                 Ok so this is what I think about this song: You need to switch back to your roots. You started as a rapper, and you need to remain a rapper. I respect you for your initiative to improve your flexibility but please stick to your roots. That's what makes you truly great. \
              </div> \
              <span class="comment_footer"> \
                 <ul> \
                    <li class="list_style">about 18 hours ago</li> \
                     \
                        <li><a href="/videos/485/comments/22" class="normal" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow">Delete</a></li> \
                     \
                 </ul> \
              </span> \
              </div> \
            </div> \
         \
     </div> \
     \
 \
<div class ="comment_column_narrow"> \
     \
    <div id = "comment_title_72" class="comment_title"> \
        sacscas \
        <a href="/comment_titles/72" class="comment_title_delete" data-method="delete" data-remote="true" rel="nofollow">x</a> \
    </div> \
         \
     </div> \
     \
 \
<div class ="comment_column_narrow"> \
     \
   <div id = "comment_title_73" class="comment_title"> \
        scascas \
        <a href="/comment_titles/73" class="comment_title_delete" data-method="delete" data-remote="true" rel="nofollow">x</a> \
    </div> \
         \
     </div> \
     \
');
```

Comment: Just look at your attribute quotes, really.

Comment: That's a Ruby error, not a JS error. Mind posting the *line number*? Do you expect someone to *manually* reparse the entire thing looking for the unexpected identifier? That's why you have a parser in the first place.

Comment: You should show the final generated Javascript code, not the ruby original

Comment: the line number is in the jquery source code.

Comment: @BoltClock... the attribute quotes? can you please be a bit more specific?

Comment: try using ' instead of " on your attribute identifiers starting on the second line. It looks like it's ending your html string in the middle of <div class ="comment_column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(".comments_div").html("...class="
```

Right there, you have closed your JS string, and the HTML that follows is being treated as JavaScript. You would need to escape quotes or use an alternate:

```
$(".comments_div").html("...class=\"...\"...");
$(".comments_div").html("...class='...'...");
```

*Either way, I just threw up in my mouth a little from the amount of HTML you are putting in JavaScript.*

**Edit**: In the updated code, the JS uses only single quotes and the HTML markup uses only double quotes...but the content from the server adds a single quote.

```
$(".comments_div").html(' \
... \
please stick to your roots. That's what makes
```

You can even see the problem in your own syntax highlighting in your question.

You can horribly hack around this with `.gsub("'",'&apos;')` in your Erb output.

Comment: btw I tried making the two outer quotes ' and all the other ". I'm still getting the same error...

Comment: @JustinMeltzer You also have single quotes in your HTML content, e.g. `class='comment_footer'`

Comment: @JustinMeltzer Your Erb/Ruby code is irrelevant. Update the entire question with just the JS code seen by the browser.

Comment: @Justin `$("comments_div").html(' ... That's what makes you`. There's your problem. Any decent syntax highlighter shows you this directly. Stack Overflow's own syntax highlighter, in your question, shows where you drop out of a JavaScript string!

Comment: @Justin I've updated my answer with a new analysis and a workaround for you.

Comment: ahhh ok... so the thing is that content is generated by the user... is there a method to escape quotes like that?

Comment: @Phorgz: Yes, indeed. Interesting how the SO highlighter doesn't seem to catch it in the right place, however. The next line resumes normal string syntax highlighting, and that line is long enough that I didn't notice it right away. In any case, it's an issue of quotes, as both of us posted.

Comment: @crazy2be The SO highlighter correctly ends the string, processes a bit of garbage, and then starts a regex literal on the slash in `</div`, which is what you see ending later in the `</li>`.

Comment: do you guys have any advice on how I could make this code cleaner? this mess is making me feel uncomfortable

Comment: @JustinMeltzer Yes, don't use .js.erb. Use actions with custom partials for each snippet you want to swap. Here's my library that I use for this: http://phrogz.net/JS/AJAXFetch/

Comment: @Phrogz: Ah! The regex is the same color as the string!

Comment: @Phrogz it seems like `'` is being replaced literally with `&apos;` and the html is not converting `&apos;` to `'`. Why is this?

Comment: the JS that the browser sees has `&amp;apos;`

Comment: @Justin Rails is probably [being over-protective](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5434767/ruby-on-rails-seems-to-be-auto-escaping-html-created-by-link-to).

Comment: @Phrogz thanks, if you have time, check out this problem i'm having: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574889/how-should-i-go-about-integrating-ajax

Answer (score 2):

The syntax highlighting here illustrates it fairly cleanly: You have your string closed by `"` that are actually supposed to be part of the contents of the string. Javascript has no way to know which `"` are supposed to be within your string, and which ones are supposed to close the string.

## Solution

Use either `'` for your outer string and `"` for your inner strings (strings within the html), or `"` for your outer string and `'` for your inner string. This way, the string will be well defined. Another option is to escape `\"` all of the quotes, but this can get messy and ugly.

**Edit**: Since your issue arises from user-generated content, you should escape your submissions either at submission time or render time. I am not familiar with the exact facilities ruby provides for this kind of thing, but there should be support in one form or another that will escape all quotes in user-generated content for you.

However, even that is kind of a workaround. You should really be putting this in proper html. If you are using it for dynamic/ajax features, then you should encode it in json, optionally enclosed within a function callback (e.g. someFunc({'data':'escaped string \'n stuff'})), depending on how you are dealing with it. In this case, there are almost certainly ways to escape data to json using ruby, with one example being [here](http://flori.github.com/json/).

Comment: thanks... I'm using `'` for the outer string and `"` for all the inner strings but still getting the same error though...

Comment: Can you post the updated code? It's hard to tell with all the quote errors glaring at me :P.

Comment: @crazy2be Since Justin doesn't feel like giving us votes for our 'hard' work, I've given you one for being correct and first. :)

Comment: @Phrogz: I have given you one as well for your comment on putting this much html in javascript :P.