# How should I go about integrating AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this really messy code in my update.js.erb file which resides in my video directory. It is called every time I add a new comment_title:

```
$(".comments_div").html('<% @video.comment_titles.each do |comment_title| %> \
<div class ="comment_column_<%= 
 case @video.comment_titles.count 
    when 1 
        "wide" 
    when 2 
        "medium" 
    when 3 
        "narrow" 
    else 
        return 
    end 
%>"> \
    <% unless @video.comment_titles.count == 0 %> \
    <div id = "comment_title_<%= comment_title.id %>" class="comment_title"> \
        <%= comment_title.title %> \
        <%= link_to "x", comment_title_path(comment_title.id), :method => :delete, :remote => true, :class => "comment_title_delete" %> \
    </div> \
        <% comment_title.comments.each do |comment| %> \
            <div class="comment_content">  \
              <%= link_to image_tag(comment.user.profile.photo.url(:tiny)), profile_path(comment.user.profile), :class => "comment_image" %> \
              <div class="textual_comment_content"> \
              <div class="comment_text"> \
                 <span class="name_link"> \
                     <%= link_to "#{comment.user.name}", profile_path(comment.user.profile), :class => "normal" %> \
                 </span> \
                 <%= comment.body.gsub("'",'&apos;') %> \
              </div> \
              <span class="comment_footer"> \
                 <ul> \
                    <li class="list_style"><%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %> ago</li> \
                    <% unless current_user != comment.user %> \
                        <li><%= link_to "Delete", video_comment_path(:video_id => @video, :id => comment), :method => :delete, :class => "normal" %></li> \
                    <% end %> \
                 </ul> \
              </span> \
              </div> \
            </div> \
        <% end %> \
      </div> \
    <% end %> \
<% end %>');
```

I also have a destroy.js.erb file which resides in my comment_title directory (because the destroy method is in the comment_titles controller) and is called whenever I delete a comment title. I want to have the same code as above in this destroy file so that when I delete a comment_title, the html code is updated. The problem is that `@video` is not defined in my comment_title directory, so I cannot just copy and paste the code from update.js.erb to destroy.js.erb. So my question is what would be the best way to have the JS call above integrated into my destroy file?

Comment: I would recommend moving all that HTML out into a partial which the `.js.erb` file then renders.

Comment: yeah good point, i'll do that right now... i hate all those "\"s

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need any javascript for destroy. When you click destroy you can just remove the div. and you won't need to update anything.

Well, actually you do need javascript but not through the controller, this can be done on the client side unless you really need to wait for a response.

## Update

This assumes you are using REST.

Ruby array to loop through and identify comment destroy links

```
<% @video.comment_titles.each do |ct| %>
    <%= link_to "Destroy comment", ct, :method => :delete, :confirm => "Are you sure?", :class => 'destroy' %>
<% end %>
```

jQuery to process the destroy link:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.destroy').live('click', function(event) {

        if ( confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this comment?") )
            $.ajax({
                url: this.href.replace('/delete', ''),
                type: 'post',
                dataType: 'script',
                data: { '_method': 'delete' },
                success: function() {
                    // the item has been deleted
                    // might want to remove it from the interface
                    // or redirect or reload by setting window.location
                }
            });
        return false;
    });
})
```

You comment controller:

```
def destroy
    @comment = Comment.find( params[:id] )
    @comment.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to :back }
        format.js { render :nothing => true }
    end
end
```

Let me know if you get any errors. I'm not quite sure about your routes so It's hard to guess everything.

Comment: no I do need javascript... you see where I have the `case` `switch`? That changes the class based on the database data, which then changes the css dnynamically. This is all based on the number of comment_titles, so I need this to be dynamically updated when I delete a comment_title.

Comment: It's very easy! I will write a jq snippet for you in a bit pal!

Comment: oh and this is a related problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5575752/is-there-a-way-to-do-this-on-the-client-side

Comment: how is the destroy link getting generated? Can you give me an array of objects that I can loop through. Is it ruby, php?

Comment: Ok, so it's obviously ruby from looking at your tag. Just give me the `@resource` variable such as `@posts` that you have and I will write a clean sip for ya bro.

Comment: I'm using ruby. The destroy link is generated by the ruby code in the example above.

Comment: what do you mean by the `@resource` variable?

Comment: i loop through `@video.comment_titles` and then (having access to the comment_title variable) `comment_title.comments`

Comment: dude! this girl just showed up to my place :) so I'm gonna be a little bit. Hope I can help you out and see you soon. @samuelgilman