# Want to evaluate an if statement every time an AJAX call for creating comment_titles is triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this if statement in my video show view:

```
<% if @video.user == current_user && current_user != nil && @video.comment_titles.count < 3 %>
    <%= link_to "Add Comment Title", "#", :id => "comment_title_link", :class => "edit" %>
    <%= simple_form_for @video, :remote => true do |f| %>
     <%= f.input :comment_title_names, :label => false, :placeholder => "Add a Comments Title" %>
      <%= f.button :submit, :value => 'Add', :id => 'add_comment_title' %>
      <div class='hint'>Let your listeners know what comments you want by adding a guiding title for them. Pose a question, ask for feedback, or anything else!</div>
    <% end %>
<% elsif @video.comment_titles.count == 3 && @video.user == current_user && current_user != nil  %>
    <p> You have reached your limit of comment titles. You can always add a new one by deleting one of your old ones. </p>
<% end %>
```

This if statement essentially evaluates `@video.comment_titles.count` to determine if the if statement or the elsif statement is true. I let users add comment_titles with ajax and so by the time `@video.comment_titles.count == 3` is true, it won't correctly evaluate the if statement since the if statement, which is in my video show view, is only called after a page reload.

I want the if statement to be called dynamically every time the number of `comment_titles` changes, which is equivalent to saying whenever the AJAX call for updating comment_titles is triggered. However, I'd rather do this on the client side than have to do it in a .js.erb file. How would I trigger this on the client side?

OK so no one has answered, so I'm assuming either I have not provided enough code, I have not been clear in what I am trying to do, or it is impossible. Which is it?

Comment: i would say you didn't provide enough code and that i am confused as to what you plan to do

Comment: How are you including the video? Is it with the HTML5 video tag, or with some plug in?

Comment: @Peter this code in in the video show view, so I have access to the `@video` instance variable.

Comment: @corroded this if statement essentially evaluates `@video.comment_titles.count` to determine if the if statement or the elsif statement is true. I let users add comment titles with ajax and so by the time `@video.comment_titles.count == 3` is true, it won't correctly evaluate the if statement since it is only called after a page reload... does that make more sense?

Comment: before anything else, i would suggest to check for current_user first instead of last. to save you some of your processing :) (just commenting while digesting what you said)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading your question again with your comment in mind, I assume that

- There is a javascript event handler for the event 'new comment title has been added'.
- The provided fragment resides withing a container of sort e.g.`<div id="add_comment_title_action">fragment</div>`
- The fragment should be refreshed every time the event handler is executed
- You've seen that is possible to load the fragment by `$('#add_comment_title_action').load('fragment_url')` but you rather just do it within the client

Let's assume that the event handler looks something like

```
$('#add_comment_title_form').submit(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $.post( 'url',
          { 'title': 'Lorem ispum dolor sit amet'}
   );
   updateFragment();       
});
```

Then you could have a function for updating the fragment

```
updateFragment() {
  // Let's assume that @video.user == current_user && !current_user.nil?
  if($('.comment_title').size() < 3) {
     // NOP add something here to handle case when a title is deleted
  } else {
     $('#add_comment_title_action').html('<p> You have reached your limit of comment titles. You can always add a new one by deleting one of your old ones. </p>'); 
  }
}
```

How the code can be made better:

- There should be some callback to check if the post request has succeeded and proceed accordingly
- You could handle the two different states of the fragment by simply hiding and showing the options depending on the state (if you can assume all the users have enabled javascript and css)
- If you decide to replace the fragment with `.html(...)` then the event handlers for the elements within the fragment should be bound with `.live(event, handler)` so that you can enable adding new comment titles after a delete has been performed

Note that every check done in the client side must be done in the server side also.

See history for completely different answer :)

Comment: To be a little more clear, `#add_comment_title` is not for adding the comment titles, but rather for hiding/showing the form right below it. The form is for adding comment_titles.

Comment: seems weird though how do you submit the form?

Answer (score 0):

I kinda get what you mean by now. You should always sync your frontend with your backend so I suggest you do an ajax request when you submit the comment. Your request should return true or false if the user can comment and if he can, post it and reload that partial. I'm not a fan or rjs(which you seem to be using) so I wouldn't know the syntax but if it was jquery I could provide you with a more detailed answer.

anyway, i'll do this in bullet points

- user submits form through ajax

  $("#add_comment_title").click( function(){
     $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       data: $("#formwhatever").serialize(),
       complete: function(html) {
         $("#divthatcontainsthatwholeifstatement").replaceWith(html);
       }
     })
   })
- backend checks if user has enough posts already. if false, return false to browser. if true, add to db and render partial

  in your controller:

  def create
     #pseudo code since im also working lol
     if user.comments.size < 3
       #save comment watever
     end

  @comments = updated comments

  respond_to do |format|
       format.js { render :partial => "partialthatcontainsthatif" }
     end

  end
- ???
- PROFIT

this "refreshes" the partial no matter what. if the user already had more than 3 comments then it will return and show that error check you have

Comment: actually I am using jQuery :P

Comment: :) also look at my comment below Aleksi's answer in case you happen to have the same confusion as he did.