# Using to_sentence with HAML and mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I know this should be pretty simple, but I am new to ruby, haml, and rails.

I want to display a list of the locations, for a specific lawyer. I want convert them `to_sentence' so there are commas after every location except the last.

This is what I have in the `show.html.haml` view.

```
%ul
- @lawyers.each do |lawyer|
  - if lawyer == @lawyer
    %li.active
      %article
        %h3= lawyer.full_name
        - unless lawyer.phone.nil?
          .phone== Direct #{lawyer.phone}
        .email
          = mail_to lawyer.email, lawyer.email
        - unless @lawyer.office_locations.empty?
          - if @lawyer.office_locations.count > 1
            .locations_list
              %ul
                %li Locations:
                - @lawyer.office_locations.each do |office_location|
                  %li.locations== #{office_location.city}
          - else
            .locations_list
              %ul
                %li Location:
                - lawyer.office_locations.each do |office_location|
                  %li== #{office_location.city}
```

Edit:
This is what I tried.

```
        - unless @lawyer.office_locations.empty?
          - if @lawyer.office_locations.count > 1
            .locations_list
              %ul
                %li Locations:
                %li== lawyer.office_locations.collect{ |p| "#{p.office_locations.city}"}.to_sentence
```

I don't know if it makes a different, but `lawyer` and `office_location` are two seperate models any they both are HABTM.

I know this is the wrong way to do it, but I can't seem to get `to_sentece` or `.pluralize` working. I tried using the answer on this post [Ruby on Rails seems to be auto-escaping html created by link_to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5434767/ruby-on-rails-seems-to-be-auto-escaping-html-created-by-link-to) but I couldn't get it working.

I'm assuming I might want to put this logic in a helper? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please post the code that doesn't work - I see neither `to_sentence` nor `pluralize` in your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line has an issue:

```
%li== lawyer.office_locations.collect{ |p| "#{p.office_locations.city}"}.to_sentence
```

You are calling `.office_locations` on each `p` from the `lawyer.office_locations` relation. I suspect you want the block to be `{ |p| "#{p.city}"}`.

If you want to pluralize "Location/s", you can call the pluralize method with an argument:
`"Location".pluralize(1)` will return "Location", and
`"Location".pluralize(2)` (or anything greater than 1) will return "Locations". So you can add this to your template:

```
%li= "Location".pluralize(lawyer.office_locations.count)
```

Comment: This is going to be a dumb question. What does the `p` in `|p|` refer to? I wasn't sure what to use here, or if I needed to define this somewhere else first. Your code isn't working for me yet, and I think that is part of my problem.

Comment: `.collect` is an iterator, so the block parameter (in this case, `p`) refers to each member of the `office_locations` collection as the block is called for that member. It's generally advisable to name the parameters them more semantically, as in `office_locations.collect {|location| "#{location.city}" }`.

Comment: Thanks @Zach I got the to_sentence working. But when I try `%li= "Location".pluralize(lawyer.office_locations.count)` i get the error `wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)`